# Waking from sleep - LM 21.2

Tags: linux-mint

I'm experiencing a issue with my LinuxMInt 21.2 system (Dell Vostro 3525) - it spontaneously wakes up from suspend after a while and then goes back to sleep.
In my attempt to troubleshoot, I first examined *NetworkManager logs* using the command **journalctl -xe | grep NetworkManager**. Here's the output during a period when I wasn't using the laptop:

```
Jan 19 19:07:25 Dell systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
 The unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Jan 19 19:07:25 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705687645.7277] device (tun0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Jan 19 19:07:25 Dell dbus-daemon[877]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.5728' (uid=0 pid=371293 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
 Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun execution
 A start job for unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun execution.
Jan 19 19:07:25 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705687645.7344] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Jan 19 19:07:25 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705687645.7345] device (enp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
 Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished successfully
 A start job for unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished successfully.
Jan 19 19:07:25 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705687645.9985] device (wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 19 19:07:26 Dell dbus-daemon[877]: [system] Rejected send message, 4 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.46" (uid=1000 pid=3295 comm="xfce4-power-manager " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="Sleep" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.5728" (uid=0 pid=371293 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jan 19 19:07:26 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705687646.5079] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 19 19:07:26 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705687646.5114] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jan 19 19:07:26 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705687646.5116] device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 19 19:07:26 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705687646.5217] device (wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 19 19:07:26 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705687646.5223] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jan 19 19:07:26 Dell dbus-daemon[877]: [system] Rejected send message, 4 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.46" (uid=1000 pid=3295 comm="xfce4-power-manager " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="Sleep" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.5728" (uid=0 pid=371293 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jan 19 20:12:57 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691577.7267] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Jan 19 20:12:57 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691577.7269] device (enp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 19 20:12:57 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691577.9541] device (wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 19 20:12:58 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691578.4643] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 19 20:12:58 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691578.5181] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Jan 19 20:12:58 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691578.5182] device (wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9144] policy: auto-activating connection 'MyWifiConnection' (7445ab05-c96d-4923-af05-a0d5e34ad09d)
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9150] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'MyWifiConnection' (7445ab05-c96d-4923-af05-a0d5e34ad09d)
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9151] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9155] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9159] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9165] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'MyWifiConnection' has security, but secrets are required.
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9165] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9168] sup-iface[b5575cd694907d90,94,wlp3s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9188] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9193] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9195] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MyWifiConnection' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9196] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MyWifiConnection'
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9196] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9196] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9196] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9197] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jan 19 20:13:02 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691582.9197] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jan 19 20:13:03 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691583.4276] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 19 20:13:03 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691583.9982] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 19 20:13:04 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691584.0065] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 19 20:13:04 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691584.0207] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.0020] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.0825] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.0826] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "MyWifiConnection"
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.0828] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.0834] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.0984] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.235
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.0998] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.1014] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.1015] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.1016] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.1018] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.1019] policy: set 'MyWifiConnection' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jan 19 20:13:05 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691585.1022] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 19 20:13:12 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691592.7128] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/48)
Jan 19 20:13:12 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691592.7209] device (tun0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 19 20:13:12 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691592.7214] device (tun0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 19 20:13:12 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691592.7219] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (20a715af-51a3-4cca-8941-99df1d01e59d)
Jan 19 20:13:12 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691592.7230] device (tun0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 19 20:13:12 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691592.7231] device (tun0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 19 20:13:12 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691592.7233] device (tun0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 19 20:13:12 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691592.7234] device (tun0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 19 20:13:12 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691592.7243] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 19 20:13:12 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691592.7244] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 19 20:13:12 Dell NetworkManager[371293]: <info>  [1705691592.7248] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 19 20:13:25 Dell systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
The unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
```

Output I get using **grep "Wake|woke|resume" /var/log/syslog**

```
Jan 19 19:07:25 Dell kernel: [1131615.367996] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Jan 19 20:12:57 Dell kernel: [1135547.521710] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
```

Command **cat /proc/acpi/wakeup** return:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GPP0      S4    *disabled
GPP1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.2
GP17      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
```

Those PCI are:

```
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
```

Is the network waking up from suspend; if so, should I disable this, and how can I do it (in BIOS there is nothing about it)?
Should I disable the two identified PCI devices, is it safe?
Or - are there additional steps I should take to address this issue? Thanks.